Does using game cartridge assets on a small-scale digital distribution infringe copyright?
For example, let's say I was writing and distributing a digital zine with a 3DS game cartridge banner on the cover, and the "Nintendo Seal" and such.
Such a work is obviously not a game (due to being a zine), and may contain other factors betraying its insincerity. But I'm unclear on whether these aspects nevertheless infringe copyright or not.

Back in the olden days, a magazine could be a game. Before the Internet, it was common to print bar-code versions of programs and games in printed magazines.

@Barmar In the real olden days, we typed them in by hand... 10 PRINT "HELLO WORLD!"

20 X=X+1 30 IF X<20 GOTO 10

@Trish  echo hD1X-s0P_kUHP0UxGWX4ax1y1ieimnfeinklddmemkjanmndnadmndnpbbn > blah.com

Nintendo is a registered trademark for Print Publications
The USPTO lists 87 registrations for the class 016 with the search term Nintendo. Class 16 is for all sort of print products, such as:

PUBLICATIONS, NAMELY, [ MAGAZINES AND ] BOOKS, OPERATION MANUALS AND OWNERS' MANUALS RELATING TO VIDEO GAME MACHINES AND SOFTWARE [ AND FOR WRITING PADS AND SCOREPADS]


Printed matter and publications, namely, [ children's books, ] magazines, books, booklets and manuals regarding video games, [ children's paperback books ] and trading cards

Among them are 1497674 (Just the word Nintendo), 1689015 (the Nintendo Cartouche) and 1570911 (the Nintendo Seal) 3114368 (the Nintendo Seal) .
That is the very class your Fanzine would be in. The template containing the seal, twice the cartouche and the bare word Nintendo.
It's not allowed for you to try to even use Nintendo in your name, or in any other way create the appearance that it is an official product of Nintendo, or a Nintendo-sanctioned or -endorsed product, unless you get a license and thus are.

Did a word get left off from your final sentence? Is the intent "are a sanctioned and endorsed product."

no word missing, it is meant to be implied: you can not appear as X unless you are [X].

Whether or not it is a copyright violation, it is, at a minimum a trademark infringement. You can't use a Nintendo trademark to distribute a product, even in a low volume, without Nintendo's permission.
The details of the zine are not discussed in enough detail in the question to know if it is a derivative work which is also copyright infringing.

I believe it's my misunderstanding that led to a question about copyright rather than trademark; you appear to have answered to satisfaction my real concern.
